# Riemannian metric on the Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M = \Bbb{R}^n$ with standard metric,define the distance function $r(x) = |x| = \sqrt{x^2_1+...+x^2_n}$.

Prove the Riemannian metric on $M\setminus \{0\}$ can be written as $$g = dr^2 + r^2 g_{n-1}$$
where $g_{n-1}$ is the round metric on the unit sphere.

My attempt,First since $\Bbb{R}^n$ is flat,there exist a coordinate frame which is orthonormal frame,denoted  it by $(r,u_2,...,u_n)$.(Or you can show there is a local coordinate s.t. $(u_1=r,u_2,...,u_n)$ by canonical form of vector field near a regular point)

by the Gauss lemma, the coefficient before $dr^2$ is $1$ ($g_{rr} = g(\partial_r,\partial_r) = 1$),and the coefficient between direction $r$ and another direction $(u_2,...,u_n)$ tangent to the sphere(the level set of $r$) is 0.

so$$ g= dr^2 + u_{i,j}du^{i}du^j$$

Only needs to show the second term is $r^2g_{n-1}$.Consider any two vector $(v,u)$ tangent to the sphere $S_r$,we know $g(v,u) = g_{S_r}(u,v) = dr^2(u,v) + u_{i,j}du^du^j(u,v) =  u_{i,j}du^du^j(u,v)$ where $g_{S_r}$ is the round metric on the sphere of radius r.

So $g = dr^2 + g_{S_r} = dr^2 + r^2 g_{n-1}$.

Is my proof correct,is there some better proof?

Comment: If you already know that the metric on the sphere of radius $r$ is $r^2g_{S_1}$, where $g_{S_1}$ is the round metric on the sphere of radius 1, then your proof looks OK to me

Comment: this can be done by restrcting the linear map $c_r:x\mapsto rx$ from $\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^n$ to unit sphere $S_1 \to S_r$ @Didier